# Defining a class member that can be of multiple data types

Tags: c#

I have a class member that can take multiple datatypes as shown in the image below.[image].

How do I define such a data member within the class which can take a datatype from one of the mentioned types.Thanks

Comment: Make an object.

Comment: Create a generic class and define the type when you instantiate it

Comment: Would generics work for you?

Comment: Use a [generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) type

Comment: C# is a statically typed language. A variable once assigned a value can't changes its data type during its life-time.

Comment: @RBT: It's got nothing to do with "once assigned a value" - it's at the point of *declaration* that the type is specified.

Comment: All those types derive from "object" so use it.

Comment: Would be better if you explained what you want to do.

Comment: I second @Bahrom. The current structure of the class which you have got so far will be helpful to nail down your issue better.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Object is the common data type,you could manipulate it this way.

```
    private object _classmember;
    public object classmember
    {
        get { return _classmember; }
        set
        {
            _classmember = value;
            if (_classmember.GetType()==typeof(Boolean))
            {
              //Do your stuff
               MessageBox.Show("boolean");
            }

            if (_classmember.GetType() == typeof(int))
            {
              //Do your stuff
                MessageBox.Show("int");
            }

            if (_classmember.GetType() == typeof(double))
            {
              //Do your stuff
                MessageBox.Show("double");
            }
              //Declare all the necessary datatypes like the above
        }
    }
```

Usage will be like

```
       classmember = true;
        classmember = 1;
        classmember = 6.6;
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare it as `object` you can later test it with `is`:

```
public object MyProperty { get; set; }

public void DoSomething()
{
    if(MyProperty is bool)
    {
        bool mp = MyProperty as bool;
        // do something with boolean type mp
    }
    else if(MyProperty is string)
    {
        string mp = MyProperty as string;
        // do something wit string type mp
    }
    // ....
}
```

In newer version of Visual Studio (I think version 2015 upwards) you can combine the type check and the cast:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    if(MyProperty is bool mp)
    {
        // do something with boolean type mp
    }
    else if(MyProperty is string mp)
    {
        // do something wit string type mp
    }
    // ....
}
```

The benefit of this approach, in comparison to a generic class, would be that the properties type could change during the objects lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a generic class:

```
public class MyThing<T>
{
    public T MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And now you say what the type is going to be when you create the class:

```
var myIntObject = new MyThing<int>();
var myStringObject = new MyThing<string>();

myIntObject.MyProperty = 5;
myStringObject.MyProperty = "Hello world";
```

Comment: I like this approach. But it has a limitation if the type of the assigned value could change in the objects lifetime. We can't know it without OP telling more about his use cases. If the type won't change the generics approach is a lot cleaner

Comment: Well yes, that's possible, but I would posit that if a data type is changing over an objects lifetime, that there's a code smell there that likely needs fixing.

Comment: I totally agree with that

Comment: We both chose Hello World for string and 5 for int :D I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé `But it has a limitation if the type of the assigned value could change in the objects lifetime.` The approach here still allows you to use  `MyThing<object>()` if you want to support multiple types.

Comment: To allow support for multiple types. So you can have type safety when you want it, and disable it when you don't.

Answer (score -2):

In most languages there is the Object datatype which all other datatypes inherit from.